# is.na to convert na in to string in R

Tags: r, variables, na

I want to convert my numeric variable into a categorical variable. However there is 11000 NA value in this variable in the data set, i also interested in. So i assigned an "unknown" to variable has na value by using the code below:

```
loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatioGroup[
  loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatio > 0.2 ] <- "Good"

loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatioGroup[loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatio <= 0.2 & loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatio >0.15 ] <- "Caution"

loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatioGroup[
  loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatio< 0.15 ] <- "Danger"

loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatioGroup[is.na(loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatio)] <- "Unknown"
```

But when I doing

```
count(loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatioGroup)
```

it still have a category which is na, How can i put them all into Unknown, and why this happened? Thankyou

Good    57092
Caution 18237
Danger  26711
Unknown 8554
NA  3338

Comment: Please provide some sample data. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.

Comment: count is not part of base R: non reproducible/

Comment: How did you define `DebtToIncomeRatioGroup`?  Is there a category you aren't accounting for?  I suspect the root of your problem occurs somewhere before the code you are showing here.

Comment: I put the code before on the posting

Comment: What happens at loan_data_10v$DebtToIncomeRatio= 0.15?

Comment: You should look into the `cut` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the values ​​equal to 0.15 in any category.

Comment: ....it is because of that. Thank you so much!